# How to interpret $\Box\Box A$ in the possible worlds

Tags: logic, modal-logic

The possible world semantics (Kripke semantics) defines $\Box A$ as follows:
$$
v(\Box A, \omega)=T\iff \forall \omega'\in W\:(\omega R\omega'\land v(A,\omega')=T)
$$
And so
$$
v(\Box\Box A, \omega)=T\iff \forall \omega'\in W\:\forall \omega''\in W\:(\omega R\omega'\land\omega' R\omega''\land v(A,\omega'')=T)
$$
This is clear for temporal logic, i.e. $\Box$ means *always*. But if $\Box$ means *necessary*, it is unclear to me. So how is it interpreted for *necessary*? Any thought is welcome.

Comment: $\Box$ isn't interpreted as *possible*, but rather *necessary*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line says "$A$ *necessarily* holds in wolrd $w$ iff $A$ holds in all worlds reachable from $w$". You can think of it as, $A$ *necessarily* holds in wolrd $w$ iff $A$ holds all around as far as one can see from $w$. If you've traveled everywhere in your reach and in all that map you see $A$, you believe that $A$ holds necessarily, it is a law for you.

The second line says "$A$ is *necessarily necessary* in $w$ iff $A$ holds in all worlds that are reachable from all worlds that are reachable from $w$".

Assume that $R$ is reflexive. If $\Box\Box A$, then by setting $w'=w$ in the interpretation, you get a result equivalent to the interpretation of $\Box A$. This justifies $\Box\Box A \to \Box A$.

Assume that $R$ is transitive. Quoting Alex Kruckman from the comments,

> If $A$ is true at every world reachable from $w$, then $A$ is true at every world reachable from every world reachable from $w$, since all such worlds are reachable from $w$.

This justifies $\Box A\to\Box\Box A$. After all, if something is necessary, it is necessarily necessary.

Comment: I think you have the implications corresponding to reflexivity and transitivity the wrong way round.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don't think so... Where exactly is the error?

Comment: Suppose $R$ is transitive. If $A$ is true at every world reachable from $w$, then $A$ is true at every world reachable from every world reachable from $w$, since all such worlds are reachable from $w$. So $\square A \rightarrow \square\square A$.

Comment: On the other hand reflexivity is not sufficient to justify this implication. Suppose we have worlds $a$, $b$, $c$, each reachable from themselves, with $b$ reachable from $a$ and $c$ reachable from $b$, and no other relations. If $p$ is true at $a$ and $b$, but not at $c$, then $\square p$ is true at $a$, but $\square \square p$ is not true at $a$.

Comment: Yes, excuse me for that existential there. I have understood it's wrong. I'll delete that comment. I'm trying to grasp the situation here, because on the one hand I see why you're right. But I don't see why what I write in my answer is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing necessity and possibility? Suppose we have $\lozenge \lozenge A$ true at a world $w$. Then there is a world $w'$ which is is reachable from some word reachable from $w$. If $R$ is transitive, then $w'$ is reachable from $w$, so $\lozenge A$ is true at $w$. Thus, if $R$ is transitive, we have the validity of $\lozenge \lozenge A\rightarrow \lozenge A$ (this is the contrapositive of $\square A\rightarrow \square\square A$, with $A$ replaced by $\lnot A$).

Comment: That is, in your argument you reasoned about a particular world $w'$ reachable in two steps from $w$, which naturally gives you a conclusion about $\lozenge$. To get a conclusion about $\square$, you need to reason about *all* worlds reachable in two steps from $w$.

Comment: Thank you @AlexKruckman. I have updated the answer.